# Sequelize chaining methods

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I really like Resql that changing sequelize's function of:

```
students.find({where: {id: 34235}}).success(function(student) {
    student.getCourses().success(function(courses) {
        console.log(courses);
    });
});
```

To:

```
students.one({id: 34235}).courses().then(function(courses) {
    console.log(courses);
});
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this now with sequelize?

For example:

```
models.User.find(1).getProducts()
```

I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Promise] has no method 'getProducts'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible in sequelize - node is async by nature, and thus you have to way for the user to be found before you can call `getProducts`.

However you can use includes:

```
User.find({ 
  where: {
    id: x
  }, 
  include: [Course]
}).then(function (user) {;
```

This will left join user with course and you will be able to access `user.course` (or `user.Course`, depending on the name of your course model)